# How can I deploy a web application onto an existing domain Meteor javascript

Tags: javascript, heroku, deployment, meteor

I am about to deploy my first client facing application built on Meteor JS. My client has a website - www.samplewebsite.com and I want to add my application's routes to that site so it would be www.samplewebsite.com/admin, www.samplewebsite.com/store, etc. instead of www.newapplication.meteor.com. I plan on using Heroku to host the application. Can someone point me to where I can find more information on how to do this? I apologize if the question is unclear since I am still learning the technical syntax.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the meteor buildpack from https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor

Do this in your meteor app's directory on your local machine:

Create a git commit

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Create an instance:

```
heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor.git
```

Configure your app:

```
heroku addons:create mongolab:sandbox
heroku config:add MONGO_URL=<insert_value_of_MONGOLAB_URI_here>
heroku config:add ROOT_URL=<insert_url_created_above_here>
```

Then deploy it to heroku:

```
git push heroku
```

From this point you can use the guide here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains to set up your domain to match the heroku instance.

This way you can now use your own domain for your app.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MUP](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up). Its a command line tool and allows for very easy deployments.